# Finding the reduced pressure to distill a solution containing 0.4 g of naphthalene in 25 g of chloroform at 50 °C

Tags: physical-chemistry, colligative-properties, liquids

> Chloroform boils at $\pu{62 ^\circ C}$. For a solution containing $\pu{0.4 g}$ of naphthalene in $\pu{25 g}$ of chloroform, the boiling point is elevated by $\pu{0.45 K}$, to avoid any decomposition during distillation chloroform has to be distilled at $\pu{50 ^\circ C}$, what maximum pressure can be maintained in the flask?

My approach:
I found the molality of the solution to be $0.125m$, equating it with the formula $$\Delta T_\mathrm b=K_\mathrm b\cdot m$$ I found $K_\mathrm b$ to be $3.6\ \mathrm{K\ kg/mol}$, I am not able to proceed after this step, please provide an approach to solve the problem from here.

I also tried using the formula $$\Delta K_\mathrm b=\dfrac{R {T_\mathrm b}^2}{1000l_\mathrm v}$$ but finding out the latent heat of vaporisation did not prove to be of any help.

Comment: Apply the Clausius-Clapeyron integral equation, as you know vapour tension at 2 temperatures(on indirectly ). Then you can calculate the tension at the 3rd temperature.

Comment: Can you provide your approach in detail in the answer, I am not able to apply the Clausius-Clapeyron equeation

Comment: I can,but I will not. Try harder. If I consider the time delay of your comment and time to write and post it, you could hardly have a good look at it. Consider also the Raoult law to get the 2nd vapour tension.

Comment: @Poutnik Is your answer 509.6 torr, I am asking this just to be sure?

Comment: Particular answer is of no importance, the principles and procedures are what matters. Otherwise it qualifies well for the closure as a homework-like question.

Comment: @Poutnik you can close my question if you want to, but please let me know at least that my work on this question is correct or not, I have solved it using Clausius-Clapeyron equation and obtained the answer, I have to know to confirm that I understand the equation well

Comment: Present your work first, putting it to the question. If you are not sure,comment why you think it may be wrong. Be aware SE chemistry site is not a homework solver nor homework proof reading service. It helps to understand principles and to solve non trivial tasks.

Comment: Technical note: Question titles should be like book titles. They distinguish books from each other, but give just a hint about the content, not being as much particular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111824/discussion-between-poutnik-and-shriom-kumar-singh).

Comment: Identify sources where the Clausius-Clapeyron equation is applied and work these examples _multiple times_ (e.g., https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/States_of_Matter/Phase_Transitions/Clausius-Clapeyron_Equation), (yet your course notes may contain similar examples, too) until you feel good enough to explain them to someone else. Have a break. Solve them without seeing their answers. Pause. With a fresh mind, return to the problem of your question here.